# Placing a character randomly in a string

Tags: php

```
$string = "Hello World";
```

I want to place "_" randomly in $string so the output would be,

_H_e_ll_o W_orl_d

I've searched and I'm unable to find a working solution.

Comment: First: What have you tried. Second: Why would you do that?

Comment: I'm just messing around with strings and wanted to do it. Secondly I've tried str_shuffle however I don't want the output to be: hllowerld

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a question?

Comment: And how many `_`s do you want to put in there?

Comment: I think a random amount which can't be more than the amount of characters in the string @Hanky웃Panky

Comment: I'd like to put 1,10 inside the string.

Comment: `More than the amount of characters` still doesn't tell how many

Comment: Can't you read? `can't be more`

Comment: And how less it can be ? :) `cant be more` just gives you one boundary

Comment: Thats what I said a random amount of `_`s bigger than 0 of course.

Comment: Ok great, makes sense. We already have a good answer :)

Comment: Not necessarily amount of `_` can still be 0. Small chance though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mt_rand(0, 1)` randomize! May be this code might work!

```php
$string = "Hello World";
$string = str_split($string);
$final = "";
foreach ($string as $char)
  $final .= ((mt_rand(0, 1) == 0) ? "_" : "") . $char;
echo $final;
```

After running a few times, I am getting this input:

```
H_ello W_or_l_d
He_llo W_o_rld
H_e_ll_o _W_o_r_ld
_Hell_o _W_orl_d_
He_l_lo _Wor_ld
_He_ll_o Wor_ld
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on [Praveen Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/462627/praveen-kumar)'s answer, but with more of a functional twist, we might do:

```
function underscorize($s, $t)
{
    return $s . ((mt_rand(0, 1) == 0) ? "_" : "") . $t;
}

$string = "Hello World";
echo array_reduce(str_split("Hello World"), "underscorize");
```